# quick question on surface integrals/stokes theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say if I have a cylinder with the bottom removed I have an open surface. When we apply stokes theorem (or carry out the surface integral) are we just summing over the outer surface or the surface inside the cylinder aswell?

Comment: What is the difference?  Choose an orientation for the surface, which is based on a clock-wise or counter clock-wise path for the line integral.  In one-choice the normal to the surface will point "out of" the cylinder and in the other choice it will point "into" the cylinder.  Then, the surface integral in Stoke's Theorem will be well-defined.

Comment: Forget stokes' theorem for a second, if we were working out the surface area of the open cylinder we would include the opposite side of the outer surfaces as well? ( The inner surfaces of the cylinder)

Comment: No.  When you find the length of an arc, do you consider both sides?

Comment: I really hoped that I could help.  So, please let me know if there is any way that I can improve my answer.  I just want it to be the best possible answer for you.

Comment: I understand what you have stated below, however why does it imply that we only sum over the outer surface and not the inner also? I understand that it is the same surface, I'm just confused by the fact that I were to work out the surface area of a cup ($\cup$) I would have thought you would include the surface inside also to get twice the surface area of the outer surface.

Comment: Well, as thin as a cup might be, it is not infinitesimally thin.  It actually has volume and therefore the surface is closed.